# Wildcard subdomains routing with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've been trying to wrap my head around this concept and how to route it correct but i just have a hard time doing that.

I'm accepting all domains and subdomains to my app but here's the issue:

Example:

```
john.myapp.com/foo
```

it should route to the `foo` function in the `user` controller instead of calling a controller called `foo`.

So:

```
john.myapp.com/foo -> myapp.com/user/foo
john.myapp.com/foo/bar -> myapp.com/user/foo/bar
someotherdomain.com/foo/bar -> myapp.com/user/foo/bar
myapp.com/foo -> the controller: foo
```

But this routing should only apply to subdomains and other domains, not `myapp.com`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Codeigniter doesn't support routing involving domains as part of it's default functionality.

If you visited `www.example.com/controller/method` the router interprets only the `/controller/method` part and ignores anything before.

This means to achieve what you're trying you need to route the subdomains to the application using .htaccess.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www\.)(?!myapp\.com)[^\.]+)\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/user/%1/$1 [L]
```

This would send all requests like

`subdomain.example.com/controller/method` go to `example.com/index.php/user/controller/method`

This will allow you route depending on the subdomain using the standard routing functionality.

Comment: but how can I route it to a user.example.com who is dynamically created